# The puzzle of the day

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is called Hidato or Snake Puzzle !

The goal of Hidato is to fill the grid with consecutive numbers that connect horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. For your help, the grid is already filled with a few numbers.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"?

Comment: The previous number and the next number must appear in the 9 boxes surrounding a number

Comment: Is there any rule about the consecutive-numbers path crossing itself? If not, it seems solutions must be non-unique. Look at the 129 and 132 on the right: some logic may determine whether 130 and 131 are *above* or *below* those two, but how do we know which way round the 130 and 131 are? Seems like, given that they're say above the given two, 130 and 131 could be swapped around without affecting anything else in the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

> [image]

The snake does cross itself, though. It isn't mentioned in the OP if this is allowed or not.

Comment: There is a crossing between 7-8 and 17-18 and between 135-136 and 149-150.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, nicer in my opinion...

> [image]