# Another puzzle combination (feat. Kakuro)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Today, I am going to give you another puzzle combination. This time, it features a Kakuro! However, there are some things to note:

> 1. There are only two puzzles that I have combined, although you have to figure out which other puzzle I combined with it.
> 2. Unlike what the rules of Kakuro state, there are numbers larger than 9, however no smaller than 1.

Rules of Kakuro:

> 1. Place numbers in the white squares of the grid.
> 2. (except for this puzzle, where you are allowed to place larger numbers) You must place the numbers 1-9 only.
> 3. Numbers cannot repeat. (especially with this puzzle - each number that you use can only be used once)
> 4. The numbers in each run of squares must sum to the number given at the start of that run.

The puzzle:

> [image]

To get the $\color{green}✓$:

> 1. Solve the Kakuro
> 2. Figure out what the other puzzle is

<sub>Edit: Had to fix accidental incorrect sum, 21 is now 22</sub>

Comment: Are you sure about that 81? I'm getting it to be 82.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Just checked with WA (wolfram alpha), yes it's 81

Comment: The horizontal clues total 351. The vertical clues total 350. The incorrect clue is not 81 as @Randal'Thor guessed. It is 21, which should be 22.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ah, thanks for telling me. will fix that.

Comment: And fixed my solution accordingly, as well as figuring out the name of the other puzzle. Thanks @DanielMathias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that's an unusually neat Kakuro solution:

> [image: final solution]

Presumably the other puzzle is something that involves

> creating a sort of "snake" of numbers in boxes going all over the board, forming a loop that starts from 1 and goes up to 26.

Yep, apparently it's called

> [Hidato](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/96978/5373) (and I've actually solved both the puzzles in my intuitive understanding of what must be going on with the sequence of numbers here).

Comment: About your last spoiler, no, although you were onto something with your second to last one. (sorry if there being numbers going up to 26 was a red herring though)

Comment: That other puzzle has appeared in several recent questions asked here by a certain user.